# Redirect everything to language specific https sites

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I would like to do the following redirection:

- Go to the English site if there is no data about language
- Go to the Hungarian site when the user's browser language is Hungarian
- Go to the English site when the user's browser language is not Hungarian

I use the following commands in my Apache conf:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]*/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (hu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/hu [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (!hu) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.net/en [L]
```

The problem is when I request only `https://example.net`, there is no redirection, only the files in the root folder are listed.

EDIT: The current rewrite rules:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    # This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} hu [NC]
    RewriteRule !^/?hu https://example.net/hu [L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !hu [NC]
    RewriteRule !^/?en https://example.net/en [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please post your entire server config (or at least the relevant sections - virtual hosts etc). It seems from your output (as discussed in comments below) that HTTP and HTTPS are behaving differently, which suggests you've got these directives in the wrong place (and you are not canonicalising HTTP to HTTPS).

Comment: FYI Regarding the bounty you had offered on your question... since you added the bounty _after_ the answer was already posted, you would have needed to have manually assigned this bounty before the grace period ended (if that was your intention). The bounty is not automatically assigned in this scenario; it is simply lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^[^.]*/$
> ```

This *condition* will prevent requests for the document root being "redirected". (Not too sure what the idea behind this directive is?)

You should also modify the `RewriteRule` *patterns* to exclude the `/hu` and `/en` directories respectively, to avoid an unnecessary (additional) loop. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?hu https://example.net/hu/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?en https://example.net/en/ [R,L]
```

Note that since `/hu` and `/en` are physical directories then you should include a trailing slash on the target URL. Otherwise, mod_dir will issue a second 301 redirect to append the trailing slash.

However, this logic is flawed. The `Accept-Language` header can contain several languages. And each language can be "weighted", indicating the users preference. With your logic, the Hungarian site would be displayed for a user that accepted Hungarian, but preferred English. A simplified solution is to *assume* that the preferred language is the first language stated, in which case, change the *CondPatterns* to `^hu` and `!^hu` respectively. However, this won't necessarily be reliable in all cases.

And... for SEO (and users) then you should probably not redirect at all and simply allow the user to decide - perhaps *recommending* a language version based on the perceived language preference. Apart from being "unreliable" (as noted above), if you force redirect then search engines are likely to only ever see one version. For search engines, you should make sure you have the appropriate [`<link HREFLANG>` elements](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077). See also the Google Help docs: [Managing multi-regional and multilingual sites](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/182192?hl=en)

> files in the root folder are listed.

*Aside:* If the files are *listed* then it sounds like you need to disable directory indexes. Either remove the `Indexes` option from the main `Options` directive, or disable the option in the virtual host:

```
Options -Indexes
```

---

**UPDATE#1:** The problem that is not immediately obvious from your question is that you are getting a different response from HTTP than you are from HTTPS. The HTTP request would seem to be working "OK" (after having removed the `RewriteCond` directive above), but it's the HTTPS request that is not working as required. In fact, requesting `https://example.net/` appears to be bypassing your directives completely.

This difference between HTTP and HTTPS implies the directives are in the wrong place in your server config, since HTTP and HTTPS requests are usually processed by different virtual hosts. Having looked at your config files this does indeed seem to be the problem.

You have 2 `<VirtualHost>` containers, one for port 80 (HTTP) and the other for port 443 (HTTPS). The mod_rewrite directives above are only in your port 80 vhost, so they are only being applied to HTTP requests, not HTTPS.

I'll assume that you want to canonicalise the request, so that all HTTP requests are redirected to HTTPS.

You need to do the following:

1. Move the above directives from the `<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>` container and put them in `<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:443>` instead. You don't need the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper.
2. In the `<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>` container (that previously contained the above directives) issue the HTTP to HTTPS redirect using a mod-alias `Redirect`:

   ```
   Redirect 301 / https://example.net/
   ```

   However, if you have plans to implement [HSTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security) then you should instead use mod_rewrite here (to redirect to the same host):

   ```
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
   ```

   (Or... you will need to split each of your current vhosts into www and non-www versions, rather than having just two vhosts, each covering www and non-www.)

So, you end up with something like the following:

### indikatrix.net.txt

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:80>
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/

    ### OTHER DIRECTIVES HERE... ###

    # Redirect all requests to HTTP
    Redirect 301 / https://example.net/ 

    ### OTHER DIRECTIVES HERE... ###

</VirtualHost>
```

### indikatrix.net.ssl.txt

```
<VirtualHost X.X.X.X:443>
    ServerName example.net
    ServerAlias www.example.net
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.net
    DocumentRoot /home/example/public_html/

    ### OTHER DIRECTIVES HERE... ###

    RewriteEngine on

    # Language redirect...
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} hu [NC]
    RewriteRule !^/?hu https://example.net/hu/ [R,L]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !hu [NC]
    RewriteRule !^/?en https://example.net/en/ [R,L]

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/indikatrix.net.cert
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/indikatrix.net.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/indikatrix.net.bundle
    SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ### OTHER DIRECTIVES HERE... ###

</VirtualHost>
```

However, also note my comments above about the potentially *flawed logic* and consider changing the regex in the above directives accordingly.

Also, which is not covered by the above (and neither addressed in your question) is what should happen to a request such as `https://example.net/foo/bar`? Currently, this will redirect to `https://example.net/hu/` (or `/en/`). Should this not redirect to `/hu/foo/bar` (or `/en/foo/bar`)?

**UPDATE#2:**

> 1. Why the `/hu` page loads for me, if my browsers language are English?

Because I suspect your machine also supports "Hungarian". That is the problem with the above "logic" (as mentioned earlier). The `Accept-Language` request header is more complex, it contains a string of the form:

```
en-GB,en;q=0.9,hu;q=0.8,id;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.6
```

Even if Hungarian is not the primary language, if it is installed then "hu" is contained in the header. You can perhaps change the regex to match `hu` at the start of the string instead (rather than *anywhere*) - as mentioned above. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?hu https://example.net/hu/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/?en https://example.net/en/ [R,L]
```

However, this is still an oversimplification.

> 2. Sources from subdirections don't load now (like `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../indikatrix.css"/>`), what can be the reason? (if the file is on the root)

Because the above directives redirect *everything* to either the `/hu` or `/en` subdirectory. You need to modify the above directives so that requests for existing files are ignored. If you don't have other directives that need to be processed (you don't at the moment) then you can do this in one go before the existing directives:

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

If a request maps to an existing file then processing is stopped. You could optimise this so that it only targets CSS, JS and images (bear in mind that this means that CSS, JS and images will never be redirected):

```
RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ - [NC,L]
```

You should avoid using *relative* paths to your static resources, to avoid problems in the future if you decide to rewrite the URL. So, instead of referencing the CSS file in the document root using a relative URL-path like `../indikatrix.css`, use a root-relative path instead: `/indikatrix.css`.

---

**UPDATE#3:**

> if I would like to load: `https://example.net/hu` then `https://example.net/en` forced.

If you want to be able to override the redirect (based on the `Accept-Lanaguage` header) then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to `!^/(en|hu)` for both rules.

### Summary

```
Options -Indexes -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ - [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/(en|hu) https://example.net/hu/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} !^hu [NC]
RewriteRule !^/(en|hu) https://example.net/en/ [R,L]
```

Comment: I am working with a VPS server, I've disabled this option in the main .cfg:  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks by adding a hash, and checked in the vhost.cfg. But the server still loads the root folder. And the server still loads http sites as well: like http://example.net/hu :=(

Comment: You shouldn't remove that directive completely (by commenting it out). Just remove the `Indexes` option. ie. `Options FollowSymLinks`. (`FollowSymLinks` is required by mod_rewrite.) If you are still seeing directory listings then `Indexes` must be getting set _somewhere_. However, with the updated mod_rewrite directives above then the request shouldn't be hitting your root folder anyway?

Comment: And what about this (it's in the main.cfg):
<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
</IfModule>

But there is no index.php file on the root.

Comment: Yes, that is OK. That instructs Apache to serve `index.php` (or `index.html`) when requesting a directory but _only if it exists_. (If you have a directory index document in that directory then it will also prevent a directory listing, however, it is better to simply disable directory listings for all directories by removing the `Indexes` option as mentioned above.)

Comment: If I remove DirectoryIndex, or put it to the vhost.cfg, then the files are listed all the time. Probably the problem stem from that, there is no index file at the root. 
If http://example.net called, then https://example.net/hu or https://example.net/en called. But in the case of https://example.net , only the files listed.

Comment: You should not remove the `DirectoryIndex` document - that is not your problem. You don't need an index file at root either. Do `/hu` and `/en` exist as physical directories? (Add `Options -Indexes` to the top of your `.htaccess` file to prevent the directory listing. However, this is not your main problem as it shouldn't be reaching the root in the first place.)

Comment: Yes, they exist, containing index.php files. I don't have a .htaccess file, I gonna create one, as you said.

Comment: EDIT: I added it, now I have this: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server. (403 Forbidden)

Maybe, this problem is two problem, shouldn't add this to my conf (before the language conditions):

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://example.net/$1 [R]

Since a wrong load of the site is possible with this: http://example.net/hu/

And I also don't know why the browser load me the Hungarian page, if my Browser language is English. 

There is such a mess with this apache :D

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to refer to `.htaccess` (muscle memory!) - add the `Options -Indexes` directive to the same context where these mod_rewrite directives are placed, or in a `<Directory>` container that covers the document root. A 403 Forbidden is correct. ... if directory indexes are not enabled and there is no directory index document.

Comment: I've updated my answer to add the `R` flag to the `RewriteRule` directives (and removed my comment about SEO). I realise that these would have implicitly triggered an external redirect anyway - which is correct.

Comment: Do you have that HTTP to HTTPS redirect before these directives - you are missing the `L` flag on the redirect, so processing with continue. Do you have any other directives?

Comment: No, I removed it, shall I add there? Unfortunately, the problem still exist: https://example.net list files. :/

Comment: To clarify... you are restarting the Apache webserver after each change to your Apache conf file?

Comment: Yes, in a centos web panel.

Comment: Note that if `/hu` and `/en` are physcial directories then you should be including a trailing slash on the target URL. ie. `/hu/` and `/en/` respectively. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, I've just looked more closely at your earlier comment (it was missing some vital information because of the formatting)... "If `http://example.net` called, then `https://example.net/hu` or `https://example.net/en` called. But in the case of `https://example.net`, only the files listed" - there is a difference in protocol! Requesting HTTP works, but HTTPS does not. Where exactly are these directives in your config? HTTP and HTTPS are handled by different configs (virtual hosts) - (although, arguably, you should be canonicalising this with a HTTP to HTTPS redirect).

Comment: By adding this extra line to the beginning of rewrite block, the http - https problem can be solved: RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// domain.net/$1 [R]

Comment: But the file listing of the "https:// domain.net" still exist. I cannot redirect it.

Comment: Where exactly are you putting these directives? If `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https:// domain.net/$1 [R]` is "solving the http - https problem" then it suggests some of these directives are in the "wrong place" in your config file. As mentioned above HTTP and HTTPS are probably using different configs (different virtual hosts). And you are getting a different result for HTTP and HTTPS? When you are accessing your site via HTTPS then these directives are not even being processed (at least that's what it looks like). Please add the necessary server config to your question.

Comment: I uploaded the three config files here (docdroid.net):
https://docdro.id/XSnYMyz
https://docdro.id/xetqP3Z
https://docdro.id/khEXiTd

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Now it seems good, I'll accept your answer. Just two small question:
1. Why the /hu page loads for me, if my browsers language are English?
2. Sources from subdirections don't load now (like <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../indikatrix.css"/>), what can be the reason? (if the file is on the root)

Comment: I've updated my answer (update#2).

Comment: Thank you for the useful information! Unfortunately, I still have problems: I tried both (the caret, and simple hu version at redirect) - but I've discovered a new problem - if I would like to load: https://indikatrix.net/hu then https://indikatrix.net/en forced. 
And the other one is that the file still not loading, after adding the mentioned lines (RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule \.(css|js|jpg|png|gif)$ - [NC,L]) to ssl.cfg. If relative path will be problematic later, shall I duplicate the .css files ? I avoided that because I didn't want to sync every time.

Comment: In order to _override_ the language redirect then you'll need to modify the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ on _both_ rules to read: `!^/(en/hu)`. Ah yes, sorry, that was a mistake ... in a _server_ (or _vHost_) context `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` should be `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` (`%{REQUEST_FILENAME}` is used in a _directory_ context, like `.htaccess`). I would avoid duplicating files if at all possible. However, different language versions often need slight changes in the CSS to account for spacing differences etc, so this is something you might need to do anyway. Or just have a CSS _override_ file.

Comment: I've updated my answer (update#3) and corrected the `%{LA-U:REQUEST_FILENAME}` reference (and included a "summary").

Comment: Works like charm :D, thank you :) Can you please remove the exact (i......x.net) texts from your answer, I'll remove them as well. (But maybe, they aren't dangerous)